# How to include font file / assets folder to rust binary

Tags: rust, sdl-2, truetype

I am trying to build a rust game that requires text rendering. The way that I found is:

```
let font:&Font = &ttf_context.load_font(FONT_PATH, 128)?;
```

My issue is that this requires the built binary to need to have the font file. What I want is for the binary to contain the font file within itself.

I briefly tried using `include_bytes!()` and `include_dir!()` but I couldn't seem to get them to work with `&ttf_context.load_font()` which expects a &str of the path which just brings me back to the original problem and I get the error `"Couldn't open ./assets/Font.ttf"`

Is there a way to include the font file in a way such I can still get its path or is there a different way I should render text?

Edit 1: Can I combine the binary and assets folder into a single file such as a `.app` file for macOS or `.exe` on windows?

Comment: It's extremely unusual to embed all of your game assets in the binary.  Does `Font.ttf` actually exist and this is simply an issue with locating the `assets` folder at runtime?

Comment: What I was hoping for is to be able to run the program without needing the assets folder in the same directory. Is there a different way I should do this such as a `.app` file on macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get a path to the included file, since that file doesn't necesarily exist at runtime and you can only use `load_font` with files that actually exist in the file system.

Instead you can use `Sdl2TtfContext::load_font_from_rwops` with the `include`d bytes like this:

```rust
use sdl2::rwops::RWops;
let font: &[u8] = include_bytes!("./assets/Font.ttf");
let font: &Font = &ttf_context
    .load_font_from_rwops(RWops::from_bytes(font)?, 128)?;
```